# How to print local XML file through NSData?

Tags: objective-c, xml

I want to take some XML data from local path and to parse. But when I use the following code,
`NSLog` returns (content) different texts which is different from XML file. How can I get exact XML data to check it consists of correct XML data or not? When I parse, it returns nothing. I have saved the file as .xml and copied to local resource folder.

```
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"samp.xml"];
NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[xmlFileContents UTF8String] length:[xmlFileContents lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                   
NSString *content=[[NSString alloc]
                   initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                   length:[data length]
                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",content);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost assuredly an encoding problem. Make sure your xml file is in UTF8 or convert it to UTF8 before you try to create the `NSData` object. Once that's done, the following code produces the same output as input.

```
NSString *open = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: [@"~/Desktop/note" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: [open UTF8String] length: [open lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *save = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: [data bytes]];
[save writeToFile: [@"~/Desktop/note2" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically: NO encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
```

You'll probably want to use one of the `NSXML` classes, unless you want to do all of the parsing yourself.